# PHP Post throwing error with link

Tags: php, post

```
 $msg = $_POST['FirstName'] . ",\n\nThank you for your interest in the book. Click to download now. <a href="MY URL">TESTING</a> ";
```

This code is throwing an error. When I remove " it sends but does not work like linked text.
I have an auto-responder on my form. Everything works but my MSG post that goes to individual that sends form does not work properly. I am trying to also put a link in it. Look below.
Of course My Url is my url..Just hiding it here.

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape your double quotes.

```
$msg = $_POST['FirstName'] . ",\n\nThank you for your interest in the book. Click to download now. <a href=\"MY URL\">TESTING</a> ";
```

Comment: That solved the error but the auto-responder is not sending with it...if I take the link out the auto-responder works

Answer (score 1):

it is normal, because you are using doublequotes twice,

try changing to 'my url' with single quotes instead

```
$msg = $_POST['FirstName'] . ",\n\nThank you for your interest in the book. Click to download now. <a href='MY URL'>TESTING</a> ";
```